# jersey mapping json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, mapping, jersey

I have a Jersey web service that consumes a json array and tries to convert it to a list. I'm getting the following error:

**SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List, and MIME media type application/json was not found.**

Can someone explain why?

I have posted the relevant code snippets

Jersery service

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void run(List<Person> people) {
     // do something with people
}
```

Person class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
   String first;
   String last;

   // constructors
}
```

json

```
{"people":[ {"first":"Bob","last":"Jones"}, {"first":"Bill","last":"Smith"} ] }
```

jquery posting

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myurl',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'application/json',
});
```

Comment: have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179737/jersey-json-media-type-application-json-was-not-found it might help

Comment: I'm currently using jersey 1.15, so I think this might be a different issue, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a dependency on jersey-json.