# Internal Server Error: MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey-1.0

I am trying to send json objest on rest using jersey webservice .For that i am trying a simple example. but I am getting internal server error. I dont have maven project. Here is my code.I have added jars.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>DataShareWebService</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.abc.CustomerInfo.WebService</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Customer.java

```
package abc;

public class Customer {

    private int custNo;
    private String custName;
    private String custCountry;

    public int getCustNo() {
        return custNo;
    }
    public void setCustNo(int custNo) {
        this.custNo = custNo;
    }
    public String getCustName() {
        return custName;
    }
    public void setCustName(String custName) {
        this.custName = custName;
    }
    public String getCustCountry() {
        return custCountry;
    }
    public void setCustCountry(String custCountry) {
        this.custCountry = custCountry;
    }    
}
```

CustWebService.java

```
package abc
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Path("/CustWebService")

public class CustWebService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ConfigureAndrew.class);
 @GET
        @Path("/{cusNo}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Customer produceCustomerDetailsinJSON(@PathParam("cusNo") int no) {

            Customer cust = new Customer();        
                cust .setCustNo(no);
                cust .setCustName("Java4s");
                cust .setCustCountry("India");
            return cust;
        }
```

I have following jars in my Web-INF-->lib folder
 1)asm-3.3.1.jar
 2)jersey-bundle-1.14.jar 
 3)jersey-client-1.17.jar
 4)json-simple-1.1.1.jar
 5)logback-access-1.0.9.jar
 6)logback-classic-1.0.13.jar
 7)logback-core-1.0.13.jar
 8)servlet-api.jar
 9)slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
 10)slf4j-ext-1.6.1.jar

And I have added following jars in my buildpath:
1)jersey-json-1.8
2)jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
3)jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
4)jersey-media-json-jackson-2.3.1.jar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jersey + Json media type application/json was not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179737/jersey-json-media-type-application-json-was-not-found)

Comment: But i ahve already added jersey-bundle-1.14.jar and jersey-json-1.8 jars. So why it is not getting that

Comment: What should I do to resolve the problem???

Comment: `jersey-json-1.8` should be in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: Added the jar in the lib folder but still it's giving the same error

Comment: Have checked all the given answers in the below stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179737/jersey-json-media-type-application-json-was-not-found